# Is there a way to `\includeonly` when the memoir document is monolithic?

Tags: memoir, emacs, include, preamble, org-mode

When writing a `memoir` document it's easy to focus on just one chapter by using `\includeonly`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\title{title}
\author{author}

\includeonly{chap-3}
\begin{document}
\include{chap-0}
\mainmatter
\include{chap-1}
\include{chap-2}
\include{chap-3}
\end{document}
```

But when using `memoir` through `org-mode` on Emacs

```
#+title: title
#+author: author
#+LATEX_CLASS: memoir

#+INCLUDE: "chap-0.org"
#+LATEX_HEADER: \mainmatter
#+INCLUDE: "chap-1.org"
#+INCLUDE: "chap-2.org"
#+INCLUDE: "chap-3.org"
```

the document becomes monolithic and it is no longer possible to use `\includeonly`.

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \includeonly{chap-3}
```

*Is there a way to `\includeonly` when the memoir document is monolithic?*

Two more issues would be nice, but I'm not hopeful either is possible, because I believe they cannot be done directly from LaTeX.

1. Disable the output of the title page and preface.
2. Number what's being `include-ded-only` from page number 1, for convenient use as an independent handout.

If none of these questions has an answer, I'm quite content with editing the text by hand to make an individual chapter an independent article, but that doesn't fly with `memoir` because, like `koma-script`, only the book type is supported, and this requires maintaining an additional style that mimics what's done under `memoir`.

###### Edit:

##### Alternative way of asking the question

After writing a `memoir` manuscript, how can I produce a PDF document of just one chapter formatted as an independent article?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `memoir`. You should probably explain what exactly you mean by _monolithic_. I've interpreted it as the out put is one single file, not separate files. As a single file, I don't think there is much you can do without introducing extra syntax

Comment: 1, you can `\include` the titlepage, 2. the whole point of include is to preserve all numbers, you could use `\input` instead.

Comment: @daleif `\includeonly` has indeed nothing to do with `memoir`—not directly at least. I am happy to hear any ideas. Is there, for example, a way to do the effect of `\includeonly` if you are not using `\include` in the first place?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does the rephrasing under "alternative" make more sense than my original question?

Comment: do you have to solve this at the latex side eg you could have another .org file that only references one chapter, if you use `article` class option `\chapter`  acts like `\section`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It really is that simple. `Org-mode`'s `*` is reinterpreted as `\section` rather than `\chapter`, and to get rid of the stubborn remaining (empty) `Contents` it's enough to `#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}` Would you care to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Sam better if you self answer with tested code

Comment: Don't use Org-mode just plain LaTeX.